# eigen problem of random matrix

Tags: mean, eigenvalues, matrix-decomposition

Suppose I need to find the eigen vectors of a matrix $M(X)$ for any sample $X$ to be my dimension reduction projector. Then since I have samples $X_1,...,X_n$, so we propose to use the eigen vectors of the matrix $\hat{M}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n M(X_i)$, saying $\hat{B}$. The $M$ matrix is kinda Gram matrix.

I wonder if there is any relationship (or under some conditions) between $\hat{B}$ and the alternative $\tilde{B}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nB_i$, where $B_i$ contains the eigen vectors of $M(X_i)$.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since I don't follow what $M(X)$ really is--"dimension reduction projector" is a rather vague term--I am focusing on the literal statement of the question. It seems to ask, in complete generality, whether there is a mathematical relationship between the eigenvectors of the mean of a set of matrices and the eigenvectors of the matrices themselves. Is this really your question? And is so, is there anything special about the $M(X_i)$ or any connection among them we should know about?

Comment: Thanks! I am sorry for making it confusing.. It is similar to PCA idea, that eigen vectors define a reduced space on $X$ that $B^TX$ where $B$ contains the first a few eigen vectors of $M(X)$. Yes, that is what I am asking essentially - relationship between eigen vectors of mean of matrices and eigen vectors of the matrices themselves. The matrices are basically Gram matrix, saying $M_{i,j}(X)=\langle\phi_i,\phi_j\rangle_{H}$, where $\phi_i$ is some function in reproducing kernel Hilbert space $H$, that kind of maps $X$ to some feature space.